# Exp-resso Store shipping rates display live

Tags: expresso-store

I am using the UPS shipping plugin.  My customer is logged in but when they get to step one in the checkout where I display the shipping options the shipping charge is $0.00

The actual charge is not displayed until the proceed to the final step in teh checkout process

How do I display the shipping charge on this initial checkout page rather that on the final step before heading to paypal?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The UPS plugin requires that you have at least the buyers shipping city, state and zip code if I remember correctly. So you will need to collect those before you show shipping information.

I usually do this once a user has an item in their cart and do not have shipping details already saved in their profile with a modal window recommending the user get tax & shipping estimates. If your customers are going to be logged in you should just need to make sure that you have mapped the shipping fields to custom profile fields so that you can bypass collecting that information in the future and can show the shipping details on the first page.

Comment: I actually get the customer to register before the checkout page is displayed.  The shipping fields are all mapped.  After they register they are directed to the checkout with the UPS shipping options, the first choice is selected by default. but the charge is $0.00.  If you click on update total the shipping charge displays correctly  I just want the charge to be displayed as soon as they land on the page without having to click the update totals button

Comment: In that case try adding `force_recalculate="yes"` to the checkout tag for that step as long as you are on Store v2.4.1+

Comment: thanks I will give that a try!  sounds like the solution

Comment: I tried: {exp:store:checkout
    form_class="form-horizontal"
    next="new-shop/checkout2"
    force_recalculate="yes"
    }
and it does still not display the UPS rates unless you click Update Totals

Comment: Hmmmm in that case it might be an error in your version. I would recommend sending a support request directly to DevDemon in that case.

Comment: In the meantime you could use a bit of js to force the update total button to be hit on page load so your users didn't have to do it. Obviously that's not ideal but would work as a temporary measure and keep the workflow you were envisioning